# Password requirement - Not be a dictionary word or proper name

Tags: c#, security

I have to create a password strength checker the only requirement that I'm not able to get is "Not be a dictionary word or proper name." I have a 60MB text file with a ton of words. For example, when you use "test" it fails properly but if you use test123 it passes when it should fail.

My code for that is:

```
int counter = 0;
string line;
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    if (line.Contains(pwd)) { return false; }
    counter++;
}
```

How would I parse a user's password to pull out a dictionary word?

Or should I try to implement a regex to force every 3rd character to be either a number or special character and avoid the dictionary file altogether? Thanks.

Comment: You haven't defined what you want to fail. `test123` is no dictionary word. And you can't simply say "anything containing a dictionary word" since that 1) makes no sense and 2) there are very common short strings that are dictionary words, such as `a`. You don't want to deny every password containing `a`

Comment: Is "Qj16!the!#" (note "the" in the middle) valid or invalid? I ask because "test123" is not a dictionary word, it merely contains one. What is the real requirement? Can the password contain "a" or "I"?

Comment: About your "or" proposal, the idea of enforcing "every *nth* character to be of type *x*" is not going to get you far down the road to security. For one, you've advertised the first detail on how to crack it.

Comment: What do you actually want to fail? Anything with a dictionary word in it? So "apfm2*23JK20N!" should fail because it's got the word "a" in it?

Comment: @Tim and @druttka, I know. That's exactly what I said... then you have to think about 2 letter words then 3 letter words. I told them that this strict of a requirement would break security because everybody would write down their passwords near their keyboard.

Comment: @user, my initial opinion (ok, second opinion) is that you may be starting with the wrong idea in mind. I would probably do two things: search for password strength algorithms, and then possibly how to safely store passwords in a database (think: salt and hash).

Comment: @user766595, if you enforce, at-least 1 special character, at-least 1 digit, at-least 8 characters, user cannot use dictionary word or proper noun as password; no need to maintain dataset.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is virtually a denial of service engine for your app.  Import the dictionary to a SQL database and then use a SQL query to do your word matching.

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT Word FROM Dictionary WHERE @Password LIKE '%' + Word + '%')
```

Would do the job.

As other people mention you seem to be trying to ban passwords that contain dictionary words, this is pretty daft and confusing for your users and does not really offer added security.  You really should only be looking for password that ARE dictionary words i.e. test is bad but test123 is fine.  If so the SQL would be even more efficient:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT Word FROM Dictionary WHERE Word = @Passowrd)
```

Answer (score 1):

Why you don't put that in SQLite and do simple queries?

Comment: If this is c# (as tagged) linq queries are guaranteed to be available... sqlite seems overkill when you have an inbuilt query syntax

Answer (score 1):

What you really want is calculating the entropy of the password. Analyzing which subset of characters or if dictionary words are used are just tools to better estimate the entropy.

The problem with dictionary words is that they're associated entropy is often very low in compared to their length. So you should add less entropy for dictionary words than for apparently random characters.

Answer (score 0):

If Word is loaded onto your server, then you can use the internal dictionary to check against, or use a dictionary web service like [this](http://services.aonaware.com/DictService/DictService.asmx) to see if a word exists in a dictionary.  If results are returned, then you can assume that it is a dictionary word.

Answer (score 0):

I would store the words into a list on the program start and work from there.

```
List<String> words = new List<String>();

while (!file.EndOfStream)
{
    line = file.ReadLine();
    words.AddRange(line.split(","); //assuming a csv file.
}

bool passWordCheck()
{
    foreach(string x in words)
    {
        if (passWord.contains(x))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should really listen to the Security Now Podcast Episode #303. Password strength is heavily discussed.

Also see: https://www.grc.com/haystack.htm this should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the overloaded `Contains` with the `StringComparison` argument.

Here's that as an extension method:

```cs
public static bool ContainsIgnoreCase(this string input, string other)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input)) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(input));
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(other)) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(other));

    return input.Contains(other, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
}
```

Usage:

```cs
var pass = "test123";

var dict = File.ReadAllLines(@"dictionary.txt");

// (optional) filter to words 4 characters or longer (ignore if your dictionary is already filtered)
dict = dict.Where(w => w.Length > 3).ToArray();

var isDictWord = dict.Any(w => pass.ContainsIgnoreCase(w));
```